# How to extract DataSet results using a Case Statement

Tags: .net, vb.net, dataset

I have a database with the following information:

```
label     value
item1      3
item2      5
item3      12
item4      16
```

I'm filling a dataset in VB:

```
sql = "SELECT Label, Value FROM Values"
            connection = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
            connection.Open()
            command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 130
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            adapter.Fill(thetable)

            connection.Close()

            connection.Dispose()
```

What I'd like to do, is populate 4 text boxes, based on the results.  I would like to do a select case statement:

```
Select Case ds
  Case When ds.tables(0).Select("label = 'item1'")
     textbox1.text = "value"
  Case When ds.tables(0).Select("label = 'item3'")
     Textbox2.text = "value"
etc. etc.
End Case
```

Textbox1 would show '3'
Textbox2 would show '12'
etc.

How can I extract the 'value' data I'm looking for, based on the label for each?  Notice - I'll skip some records, so I can't just loop through and grab the records in order.

Comment: *Textbox1 would show '3' Textbox2 would show '5'*  No, they are both going to show `value`.  Since the SQL has no WHERE clause, the datatable could contain all those values.  I think you want to loop thru the DataTable rows, evaluate the label and assign based on that.

Comment: Right - But that's my question.  Is there a way to do that using a Case statement?

Comment: Iterate the rows in the datatable in the dataset, `Select Case dr.Field(Of String)("label")`

Comment: I should mention that you do not need a DataAdapter and DataSet to read a few rows.  Use a DataReader and for each read, evaluate `rdr.GetString(0)` to assign `rdr.GetString(`)`...`Select case rdr,GetString(0)` or even get the control from the controls collection using that name

Comment: If you make this into an answer - I'll accept it.  I was able to take your suggestion, and come up with a solution!  Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead and self answer - I would go the datareader approach